# Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, database

so I'm trying to add the table from the cvs file using the query,but whatever I do it gives some errors:

Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

This is below my code how I made the table and how I try to bulk insert but fail.
Do you guys have any recommendations?
Thank you very much.

```
    CREATE TABLE employee_details (
"ID" INTEGER,
"Name" VARCHAR(255),
"Alarm text [de-DE], Alarm text" VARCHAR(255),
"FieldInfo [Alarm text]" VARCHAR(255),
"Class" VARCHAR(255),
"Trigger tag" VARCHAR(255),
"Trigger bit" INTEGER,
"Acknowledgement tag" VARCHAR(255),
"Acknowledgement bit" INTEGER,
"PLC acknowledgement tag" VARCHAR(255),
"PLC acknowledgement bit" INTEGER,
"Group" VARCHAR(255),
"Report" VARCHAR(255),
"Info text [de-DE], Info text" VARCHAR(255),
);

BULK INSERT dbo.employee_details
FROM 'C:\temp\updatesql\KED33_FailureDescription-2022-01-21-Update1.csv'
WITH (  
        
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'

);
GO
```

this is how my csv file looks

```
ID  Name    Alarm text [de-DE], Alarm text  FieldInfo [Alarm text]  Class   Trigger tag Trigger bit Acknowledgement tag Acknowledgement bit PLC acknowledgement tag PLC acknowledgement bit Group   Report  Info text [de-DE], Info text
1   Störung_Allg_SM1    RT1: Not-Halt Betätigt  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   8   <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
2   Störung_Allg_SM2    RT2: Not-Halt Betätigt  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   9   <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
3   Störung_Allg_SM3    RT3: Not-Halt Betätigt  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   10  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
4   Störung_Allg_SM4    Druck nicht OK  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   11  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
5   Störung_Allg_SM5    <No value>  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   12  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
6   Störung_Allg_SM6    <No value>  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   13  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
7   Störung_Allg_SM7    <No value>  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   14  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
8   Störung_Allg_SM8    <No value>  Fehler  Störungen_allgemein_1   15  <No value>  0   <No value>  0   <No value>  TRUE    <No value>
```

Comment: Is it CSV? Perhaps you should use `FORMAT = 'CSV'`

Comment: @Charlieface Hi,when I used it,I got the error:
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Your **image** (which is highly discouraged as a means of providing information) appears to be a tiny screen capture of Excel as it displays your file. For people to understand your file, post an example of it as text within your question.

Comment: Do your text fields in the CSV have quotes around them?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70926778/edit) your question to include the example CSV data - as text, not an image.

Comment: Excel is a very poor tool for investigating issues with delimited text files of any kind. Amongst other things it reformats things to look like dates, often breaks Unicode characters, and hides "blank" rows and columns at the edges of your data. Even plain old Notepad is better. VS Code with the Rainbow CSV extension is also very useful.

Comment: I edited the question with the text from csv file

Answer (score 0):

So I made it work,not with the query but I imported the file as flat file and just changed the varchars from 50 to 255 and it works

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me twice first when the file location wasn't reachable from RDS so I provided the UNC path of file location.
Second when the ID column was missing from CSV file after adding the column the error resolved, here is the script I used for bulk insertion:

```
BULK INSERT tf_Positions
FROM '<file path>\\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT='CSV',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
GO
```