# BULK INSERT with delimiter in column values

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert the csv content in the table using BULK INSERT.

```
BULK INSERT temp.table
FROM test.csv
WITH
(FIRSTROW=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR='|', 
ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
```

csv files is | separated, but some columns have | in it:

```
A|B|C
value1|"text | text"|value 3
```

The suggestion changing FIELDTERMINATOR='|' to FIELDTERMINATOR='"|"' did not work for me.
I become the error: The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1."
Any ideas?

Comment: Use the [`FORMAT` and `FIELDQUOTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#format--csv) parameters.

Comment: @Larnu I become then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926778/cannot-obtain-the-required-interface-iid-icolumnsinfo-from-ole-db-provider.  FIELDQUOTE also does not seem to be recognized in syntax.

Comment: When you don't tag a version, it is *assumed* you are using a fully supported version of the product, @Dana . Presumably you are not?

Comment: If you *anen't* using a recent version of SQL Server (2017+) then I would suggest that you either change the delimiter to a different character that doesn't appear in your values or use a different tool. SSIS, for example, allows for quote identified text.

Comment: @Larnu I made a mistake. I included FIELDQUOTE and FORMAT, but instead of FIELDTERMINATOR='|', I wrote FIELDTERMINATOR='"|"'. Now it works, thanks for your help.